# Search bar places under the navigation after adding tab bar

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

There was a search bar in a tableView.
And I had a navigation controller too
the search bar was located below the navigation bar.

navigation view controller is the entry point.
relationship root view controller to tab bar controller

and search bar is created in postViewController.Swift
relationship  tab bar view controller to postViewController

the setting:

```
 searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
        searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
        searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search for the user id here ... "
        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
        //blew code hides search bar on next page
        self.definesPresentationContext = true
```

The problem is that after adding a tab bar. the search bar is behind the navigation bar.

Comment: Where have you added the tab bar?

Comment: @PGDev I added information in question.

Answer (score 0):

I created the same hierarchy as yours.

1. **View Hierarchy**

[image]

2.**PostViewController**

```
class PostViewController: UIViewController
{
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet var searchBar: UISearchBar!

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchBar
        //You can customize the controller and searchBar according to your requirement.
    }
}

extension PostViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate
{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return 3
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Hello"
        return cell
    }
}
```

3. **Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks. photos cannot be loaded. but our code is the same.but my search bar has problem.

Comment: Which photo are you talking about? What is the problem you are facing with  search bar?